# jQuery append div to a specific

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, appendto

How do I append a element a specific index of the children elements using jQuery append e.g. if I have:

```
<div class=".container">
   <div class="item"><div>
   <div class="item"><div>
   <div class="item"><div>
   <div class="item"><div>
</div>
```

and I want to append another item between the second and third item?

Comment: Presumably `class=".container"` is a typo? It's valid to have `.` in a class name, but not something you'd generally want to do.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are a few options:

```
$("div.container div.item").eq(2).after($('your html'));

$("div.container div.item:nth-child(3)").after($('your html'));

$($("div.container div.item")[2]).after($('your html'));
```

The same options, but inserting into the same position using "before":

```
$("div.container div.item").eq(3).before($('your html'));

$("div.container div.item:nth-child(4)").before($('your html'));

$($("div.container div.item")[3]).before($('your html'));
```

Comment: +1 for `eq()` method instead of the non-CSS-standard (and hence less efficient) `:eq` selector. However, be careful with `:nth-child`; unlike `eq()` and most of the rest of everything, its indices are 1-based (argh).

Comment: Men I always forget this. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 4):

`("div.container div.item:eq(1)").after("<element to insert>")`

Answer (score -1):

```
$('.container').children()[1].append('whatever');
```

Comment: this will not work since [1] returns the native DOM object which does not know about a function 'append()'

Comment: I should avoid jQuery questions.